# Swift 1.2 "Cannot express tuple conversion" error

Tags: ios, swift

This method was working fine in the last stable version of Swift, but it won't compile in Swift 1.2:

```
  final func rotateBlocks(orientation: Orientation) {
    if let blockRowColumnTranslation:Array<(columnDiff: Int, rowDiff: Int)> = blockRowColumnPositions[orientation] {
        for (idx, (columnDiff:Int, rowDiff:Int)) in enumerate(blockRowColumnTranslation) {
            blocks[idx].column = column + columnDiff
            blocks[idx].row = row + rowDiff
        }
    }
}
```

This line:

```
for (idx, (columnDiff:Int, rowDiff:Int)) in enumerate(blockRowColumnTranslation) {
```

Throws the following error:

> "Cannot express tuple conversion "(index:Int, element:(columnDiff:Int,rowDiff:Int)) to "(Int, (Int, Int))"

Any ideas about what's going on here, and how to fix it?

Comment: I got the code to compile in Swift 1.2, but had to make a lot of guesses as to the exact declarations and/or inferred types of the unlisted types of `blockRowColumnPositions`, `Orientation`, etc. Distill it down to a complete file that *should* (/did) compile.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `typealias` to simplify, but the following compiles without error for me.

```
var row: Int = 0
var column: Int = 1
struct block {
    var column: Int
    var row: Int
}
var blocks = [block]()

enum Orientation { case Up; case Down; }
typealias Diff = (columnDiff: Int, rowDiff: Int)
typealias DiffArray = Array<Diff>
typealias DiffArrayDict = [Orientation: DiffArray]

var blockRowColumnPositions = DiffArrayDict();

func rotateBlocks(orientation: Orientation) {
    if let blockRowColumnTranslation: DiffArray = blockRowColumnPositions[orientation] {
        for (idx, diff) in enumerate(blockRowColumnTranslation) {
            blocks[idx].column = column + diff.columnDiff
            blocks[idx].row = row + diff.rowDiff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same thing and was able to get this working by adding an `element:` label for the tuple:

```
for (idx, element: (columnDiff: Int, rowDiff: Int)) in enumerate(blockRowColumnTranslation) {
    blocks[idx].column = column + element.columnDiff
    blocks[idx].row = row + element.rowDiff
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go! ( according to the error in swift)

Comment: Now if anyone can explain why the `element: `  label is required but the initial `index: `  label is not, that would be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Swift bug to me.  More generally, this is busted:

```
let pair = (a: 1, b: 2)
// normally those named elements don't matter, this is fine:
let (x,y) = pair
// but add a bit of nesting:
let indexed = (index: 1, pair)
// and, error: 
let (i, (x,y)) = indexed
// cannot express tuple conversion '(index: Int, (a: Int, b: Int))' to '(Int, (Int, Int))'
```

I'd try removing the type names from the array's tuple declaration (i.e. `Array<(Int,Int)>` instead of `Array<(columnDiff: Int, rowDiff: Int)>`), see if that helps.

In other, perhaps related, news, this appears to crash the 1.2 compiler:

```
let a: Array<(Int,Int)> = [(x: 1,y: 2)]
```

Comment: I got the segfault too :-(

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys! I wound up just rewriting it as a for-loop.. it's not exciting but it seems to work okay:

```
  final func rotateBlocks(orientation: Orientation) {

    if let blockRowColumnTranslation:Array<(columnDiff: Int, rowDiff: Int)> = blockRowColumnPositions[orientation] {

        for var idx = 0; idx < blockRowColumnTranslation.count; idx++
            {
            let tuple = blockRowColumnTranslation[idx]
            blocks[idx].column = column + tuple.columnDiff
            blocks[idx].row = row + tuple.rowDiff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it makes you feel better, you can rewrite that `for` as `for idx in indices(blockRowColumnTranslation) { }`

Comment: What was wrong with mine? Also for consistency, why not leave `blocks` as an array of tuples and do it in one assignment statement?

Comment: For that matter, the truly swiftian way is to pass a block (closure) to `map`

Comment: @BaseZen, nothing at all wrong with your implementation -- I'm just a beginner and I had an assignment due :)

Answer (score -1):

```
final func rotateBlocks(orientation: Orientation) {
    if let blockRowColumnTranslation = blockRowColumnPositions[orientation] {
        for (idx, diff) in enumerate(blockRowColumnTranslation) {
            blocks[idx].column = column + diff.colunmDiff
            blocks[idx].row = row + diff.rowDiff
        }
    }
}
```